# Formtastic custom field in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I need to set a custom field in many-to-many join table. For now I can only set relation with checkboxes, but I need also set a quantity field.

My models:

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :options,  :join_table => :quotes_options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Option < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :quotes
end
```

And form:

```
  form do |form|   
    form.inputs do
      form.input :options, :as => :check_boxes,:collection => Option.all
    end
 end
```

So now it is rendered as List of checkboxes like

```
New Quote
[X]  First option
[ ]  Second option
```

The question is that in table ":join_table => :quotes_options" I have also field **":quantity"** so I would like to update it as well. So my view will be like and i will be able to save quantity in joint table

```
New Quote
[X]  First option    [       ] quantity
[ ]  Second option      [       ] quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone interested I realised it like this:

```
 form.inputs do
      Option.all.each do |option|
        form.semantic_fields_for :quote_options, form.object.quote_options.detect_or_build_by_quote(option) do |quote_option|
          quote_option.input :option_name_selected , :as => :boolean, :label => option.name
          quote_option.input :quantity , :as => :number
          quote_option.input :option_id , :as => :hidden
        end
      end
```

Quote model

```
  has_many :quote_options do
    def detect_or_build_by_quote(option)
      record = self.detect{ |quote_option| quote_option.option_id == option.id }
      if record.nil?
        record = self.new(:option_id => option.id)
      end
      record
    end
  end

  has_many :options,  :join_table => :quote_options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, :allow_destroy => true        
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quote_options , reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['quantity'].blank? or attributes['quantity'].to_f.zero? }
```